# Is it possible to customize webpack.config.js file in create react app?

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I am trying to customize `webpack.config.j`s file in my create-react-app.

I know that `webpack.config.js` file is hidden inside of the project and available using command `eject`.

However I created another `webpack.config.js` file in the root and it seems it overrides existing hidden `webpack.config.js`.

Is this safe to config `webpack.config.js` file this way? without `eject` or `craco`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Frustrating as is, i found no way of getting around Create React App.
Take a look at [this issue](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/12212#issuecomment-1342777549) that describes a way of configuring using [craco](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@craco/craco)(Create React App Configuration Override).

Answer (score 1):

It seems like it is not possible without either ejecting or using a package.

I see alot of people recommending [react-app-rewired](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-app-rewired) which is what I am going to go for for my own project.